# Create a note with Facebook connect

Tags: facebook

I am wondering if it is possible to create a note on facebook through my website using facebook connect. I have notes on my website and I essentially want the ability to be able to push them over to the user's facebook account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure - I don't think you actually can.

[The reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note) doesn't have a section on publishing (say, compared to the same page for [photos](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo))

However, this *is* a user_notes [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), so perhaps it's possible just not documented?  Or it could just be that notes are, indeed, read-only.

Answer (score 0):

As for now, the 'create' part is missing from documentation but after some experimentation it works like this with the graph api based php-sdk:

```
 public function postNote ($title, $content) {
    $note_details = array(
        'subject'=> $title,
        'message'=> $content,
    );
    $result = $this->facebook->api('/me/notes', 'post', $note_details);
}
```

publish_stream permission is required